# Automatically create new row when checkbox is ticked in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a dataset of jobs for a gardening company.

```
status   #    ID     Date       Name   Frequency
☐        4    340    09/06/20   Jack   Once Off
☐        1    543    22/05/20   Sarah  Weekly
☐        3    121    01/05/20   Emily  Fortnightly
☐        3    577    11/06/20   Peter  Once Off
```

When a booking is complete I want to check the box in the first column which will then create a new row with the following conditions

- row is created only for jobs that are "weekly" or "fortnighly". Once off jobs wont create a row when the box is checked
- The date in the new row is a week or a fortnight in the future of the original row depending on its frequency value
- The job # goes up by one from the original row #
- The ID, name and frequency rows remain the same

For example if I ticked the checkbox for the 3rd row it would create a new row like this:

```
☐        4    121    15/05/20   Emily  Fortnightly
```

Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal is possible by using a custom script. You can try [creating a bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#creating_a_bound_script) in your spreadsheet file and copy/paste this sample script below:

***[updated]***

**SCRIPT:**

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var checkbox = sheet.getActiveRange().getValue();
  var selectedRow = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var selectedFreq = sheet.getRange(selectedRow, 6).getValue();
  
  //Run if selected cell has a checkbox and ticked
  while(checkbox == true){ 
    addValues(selectedRow, sheet, selectedFreq);
    break;
  }
}

//Function to process values based on frequency
function addValues(selectedRow, sheet, selectedFreq){ 
  var number = sheet.getRange(selectedRow,2).getValue();
  var date = new Date(sheet.getRange(selectedRow,4).getValue());

  if(selectedFreq == "Fortnightly"){
    //Insert a new row after the ticked checkbox, setup a new date with 14 days (or 2 weeks), increments the # with 1 & the rest of the data are copied
    var newDate = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate()+14));
    sheet.appendRow(["",number+1,sheet.getRange(selectedRow,3).getValue(),newDate,sheet.getRange(selectedRow,5).getValue(),sheet.getRange(selectedRow,6).getValue()]);
    sheet.getRange("G"+selectedRow+":S"+selectedRow).copyTo(sheet.getRange("G"+sheet.getLastRow()+":S"+selectedRow)); //If you want to copy the rest of the columns, e.g. from range G:S
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),1).insertCheckboxes();
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),4).setValue(sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),4).getValue()).setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yy");
  }

  if(selectedFreq == "Weekly"){
    //Insert a new row after the ticked checkbox, setup a new date with 7 days (1 week), increments the # with 1 & the rest of the data are copied
    var newDate = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate()+7));
    sheet.appendRow(["",number+1,sheet.getRange(selectedRow,3).getValue(),newDate,sheet.getRange(selectedRow,5).getValue(),sheet.getRange(selectedRow,6).getValue()]);
    sheet.getRange("G"+selectedRow+":S"+selectedRow).copyTo(sheet.getRange("G"+sheet.getLastRow()+":S"+selectedRow)); //If you want to copy the rest of the columns, e.g. from range G:S
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),1).insertCheckboxes();
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),4).setValue(sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),4).getValue()).setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yy");
  }
}
```

***[updated]***

**SAMPLE RESULT:**

> Sample sheet with data

[image]

> Once script has been saved, ticked some check box on the sheet and new rows were automatically added *at the bottom* if frequency contains either "Fortnightly" or "Weekly":

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway to make it so that the new row appears below all existing data? This way I can keep up to date with upcoming jobs at the bottom.

Comment: Also will this work across a large dataset of 1000 jobs with some having up to 50 #'s

Comment: @greeny I have updated my answer's script and used appendRow() method to automatically place a new row at the bottom. As per about the large dataset, yes, the script should work just fine but please keep in mind that the script may possibly slow down when there are huge data to be processed (e.g. when you tick multiple check boxes simultaneously) and it is an expected behavior.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: One issue I have found with mapping this script to my actual dataset is that there are 50 columns to copy down into each new row. Is there a way so I dont have to do: sheet.getRange(selectedRow,5).getValue(),
      sheet.getRange(selectedRow,6).getValue(),
      sheet.getRange(selectedRow,7).getValue(), etc etc?

Comment: At the end of each appenRow() on "Fortnightly" & "Weekly", you can just add the copyTo() method (if you want to copy the rest of the columns, e.g. from range G:S) : sheet.getRange("G"+selectedRow+":S"+selectedRow).copyTo(sheet.getRange("G"+sheet.getLastRow()+":S"+selectedRow));

Comment: Im having trouble making this work with my dataset - could you edit the script you provided, so i can see it within the context of the original?

Comment: Updated the script

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure this is working. When a row that is above several others has its checkbox ticked it then overwrites all the below rows